# Ruby on Rails 5.0.2 - Multiple Nested Json Render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm having some trouble trying to render multiple nested objects in json.

Here's my script

```
def getFullSale
        sale = Sale.find(params[:id])
        render json: sale, include: [:discount_sale, :offer_sale, :mixed_payment, :product_sale => {:include => {:product_history => {include: :product}}}, :refunds => {include: :refund_products}]
end
```

This works until :product_sale, however anything after is ignored.

What I need is to include both :product_sale and :refund with nested properties.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make it work!

Credits in [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9500)

The solution was to replace the array in the include and make it like an object.

```
def getFullSale
    sale = Sale.find(params[:id])
    render json: sale, include: {discount_sale: {}, offer_sale: {}, mixed_payment: {}, :product_sale => {:include => {:product_history => {include: :product}}}, :refunds => {include: :refund_products}}
end
```

I don't know why this happens, but now is working!
And actually, changing the => to : is not a bad idea.

```
def getFullSale
    sale = Sale.find(params[:id])
    render json: sale, include: {discount_sale: {}, offer_sale: {}, mixed_payment: {}, product_sale: {include: {product_history: {include: :product}}}, refunds: {include: :refund_products}}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a silly observation, but did you try changing your `=>` to `:`

```
json: sale, include: [:discount_sale, :offer_sale, :mixed_payment, :product_sale : {:include : {:product_history : {include: :product}}}, :refunds : {include: :refund_products}]
```

Comment: Tried with
render json: sale, include: [:discount_sale, :offer_sale, :mixed_payment, product_sale: {include: {product_history: {include: :product}}}, refunds: {include: :refund_products}]

But it's the same response =(